# Week number of the month?

Tags: python, time, week-number

Does python offer a way to easily get the current week **of the month** (1:4) ?

Comment: When you reach the 29th, you are actually in the fifth week, right?

Comment: Does a week start on the first day of the month or always on Monday? Or always on Sunday? Or... ?

Comment: "week of the month" is not exactly a commonly used concept. You need to tell us what is your definition, with examples, of "week of the month" ... in particular, week of WHICH month e.g. week starts on Monday, suppose today is both Sunday and the first day of the month: do you want (previous month, week 5) or (current month, week -1 or 0) or something else?

Comment: Here's one definition: http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html

Comment: Mark Byers answer went straight to the point.

I'm accessing an Oracle DB with cx_Oracle and trying to optimize the computation time passing queries already with the month and week of the month(the table is partitioned by month and subpartitioned by week of the month, 
which John Machin link has a definition as: "WEEK_OF_MONTH field range from .. 1 to .. 5")

Comment: Just to clarify,
this was to avoid using PARTITION_KEY = ((TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM'))-1) and
 SUBPARTITION_WEEK = TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'W')) as it would invalidate the index use. 
Passing the query with the correct numbers allows using the indexes.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

In order to use straight division, the day of month for the date you're looking at needs to be adjusted according to the position (within the week) of the first day of the month. So, if your month happens to start on a Monday (the first day of the week), you can just do division as suggested above. However, if the month starts on a Wednesday, you'll want to add 2 and then do the division. This is all encapsulated in the function below.

```
from math import ceil

def week_of_month(dt):
    """ Returns the week of the month for the specified date.
    """

    first_day = dt.replace(day=1)

    dom = dt.day
    adjusted_dom = dom + first_day.weekday()

    return int(ceil(adjusted_dom/7.0))
```

Comment: adjusted_dom = (1 + first_day.weekday()) % 7 for week starting sunday

Comment: Works really well. Thank you.

Comment: If i want to search second saturdays of each month, It will fail at 7th september 2019.

Comment: for March 4, 2020 this returns 2, which is incorrect. Switched to another solution below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26662038/6072151

Comment: @JustinPoehnelt I think you've made a mistake. It should be `adjusted_dom = dom + (1 + first_day.weekday()) % 7`

Comment: @Steve I think you are considering that the week starts on Sunday instead of Monday. This function works perfect for those that consider the later

Answer (score 28):

I know this is years old, but I spent a lot of time trying to find this answer. I made my own method and thought I should share.

The calendar module has a monthcalendar method that returns a 2D array where each row represents a week. For example:

```
import calendar
calendar.monthcalendar(2015,9)
```

result:

```
[[0,0,1,2,3,4,5],
 [6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
 [13,14,15,16,17,18,19],
 [20,21,22,23,24,25,26],
 [27,28,29,30,0,0,0]]
```

So numpy's where is your friend here. And I'm in USA so I want the week to start on Sunday and the first week to be labelled 1:

```
import calendar
import numpy as np
calendar.setfirstweekday(6)

def get_week_of_month(year, month, day):
    x = np.array(calendar.monthcalendar(year, month))
    week_of_month = np.where(x==day)[0][0] + 1
    return(week_of_month)

get_week_of_month(2015,9,14)
```

returns

```
3
```

Comment: sorry, i am novice to this. How do i use this function to get week number of current date instead of inserting exact year, month and date?

Comment: @RSM - just use `datetime.today().year/month/day` :-)

Comment: using numpy for this one function is overkill - In my opinion.

Answer (score 18):

If your first week starts on the first day of the month you can use integer division:

```
import datetime
day_of_month = datetime.datetime.now().day
week_number = (day_of_month - 1) // 7 + 1
```

Comment: maybe datetime.datetime.now().day would give the today's day in the month

Comment: Thanks.
It turns out it wasn't about Python after all, but about arithmetics :)

Comment: It's not clear to me that this works. Assume your week starts on a Monday and the 1st for the month of interest is a Sunday, you'd want day of month 1 to map to week of month 1. The algorithm above will return the correct answer in this case. However, if you move to the second day, a Monday the 2nd, you'd want the algorithm to return a 2. In this case, the algorithm returns the wrong answer. Please see my answer below which returns the correct result in both cases by accounting for the offset.

Comment: It fails for the date Feb 10th 2020 case and most other cases too .It is not a generic one

Answer (score 18):

Check out the package [Pendulum](https://pendulum.eustace.io/docs/)

```
>>> dt = pendulum.parse('2018-09-30')
>>> dt.week_of_month
5
```

Comment: I've been using that solution until 2021-01-10, 2021-01-17, 2021-01-24, 2021-01-31 dates return minus values as that, respectively: -51, -50, -49, -48..  So it's kind of buggy.

Answer (score 6):

This version could be improved but as a first look in python modules (datetime and calendar), I make this solution, I hope could be useful:

```
from datetime import datetime
n = datetime.now()
#from django.utils.timezone import now
#n = now() #if you use django with timezone

from calendar import Calendar
cal = Calendar() # week starts Monday
#cal = Calendar(6) # week stars Sunday

weeks = cal.monthdayscalendar(n.year, n.month)
for x in range(len(weeks)):
    if n.day in weeks[x]:
        print x+1
```

Comment: whats `now` variable?

Answer (score 5):

Josh's answer has to be tweaked slightly to accomodate the first day falling on a Sunday.

```
def get_week_of_month(date):
   first_day = date.replace(day=1)

   day_of_month = date.day

   if(first_day.weekday() == 6):
       adjusted_dom = (1 + first_day.weekday()) / 7
   else:
       adjusted_dom = day_of_month + first_day.weekday()

   return int(ceil(adjusted_dom/7.0))
```

Answer (score 5):

```
def week_of_month(date_value):
    week = date_value.isocalendar()[1] - date_value.replace(day=1).isocalendar()[1] + 1
    return date_value.isocalendar()[1] if week < 0 else week
```

date_value should in timestamp format
This will give the perfect answer in all the cases. It is purely based on ISO calendar

Comment: If you insert  any date from 2021-1-4 to 2021-1-31, you will get a large negative number. This does not work in all cases.

Comment: @LukeDupin Thanks for the criticism. Corrected the above code

Answer (score 2):

data['wk_of_mon']  = (data['dataset_date'].dt.day - 1) // 7 + 1

Comment: This solution is already provided in another answer. If you have any different solution please mention it. If there is any change/extension required to the original answer, then edit it.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the python [calendar](http://docs.python.org/library/calendar.html#module-calendar) module

Comment: Thanks.
I knew about calendar and dateutil, but both didn't help me at that.

Comment: vito has the right answer. I used: `st, end = calendar.monthrange(2012, 6)`, `days = range(st, end+1)`, `week_days = [days[i : i+7] for i in range(0, len(days), 7)]`

Comment: Providing a link does not answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

I found a quite simple way:

```
import datetime
def week(year, month, day):
    first_week_month = datetime.datetime(year, month, 1).isocalendar()[1]
    if month == 1 and first_week_month > 10:
        first_week_month = 0
    user_date = datetime.datetime(year, month, day).isocalendar()[1]
    if month == 1 and user_date > 10:
        user_date = 0
    return user_date - first_week_month
```

returns 0 if first week

Comment: `isocalendar()` can return 53 for January 1.  Your implementation returns -52 for `weekOfMonth(2010, 1, 8)`.

Comment: I fixed the code with a check for that error, and the code doesn´t get that big and it does the job perfectly.

Comment: Returns -47 for Dates: 2012-12-31, 2013-12-30, 2013-12-31

Comment: Returns -48 for Dates: 2014-12-29, 2014-12-30, 2014-12-31

Answer (score 1):

Josh' answer seems the best but I think that we should take into account the fact that a week belongs to a month only if its Thursday falls into that month. At least that's [what the iso says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#Weeks_per_month).

According to that standard, a month can have up to 5 weeks. A day could belong to a month, but *the week it belongs to* may not.

I have taken into account that just by adding a simple

```
if (first_day.weekday()>3) :
        return ret_val-1
    else:
        return ret_val
```

where ret_val is exactly Josh's calculated value. Tested on June 2017 (has 5 weeks) and on September 2017. Passing '2017-09-01' returns 0 because that day belongs to a week that does not belong to September.

The most correct way would be to have the method return both the week number *and the month name* the input day belongs to.

Answer (score 1):

A variation on [@Manuel Solorzano's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26662038/6072151):

```
from calendar import monthcalendar
def get_week_of_month(year, month, day):
    return next(
        (
            week_number
            for week_number, days_of_week in enumerate(monthcalendar(year, month), start=1)
            if day in days_of_week
        ),
        None,
    )
```

E.g.:

```
>>> get_week_of_month(2020, 9, 1)
1
>>> get_week_of_month(2020, 9, 30)
5
>>> get_week_of_month(2020, 5, 35)
None
```

Answer (score 1):

Say we have some month's calender as follows:

```
Mon Tue Wed Thur Fri Sat Sun
                 1   2   3 
4   5   6   7    8   9   10
```

We say **day 1 ~ 3 belongs to week 1 and day 4 ~ 10 belongs to week 2** etc.

In this case, I believe the week_of_month for a specific day should be calculated as follows:

```
import datetime
def week_of_month(year, month, day):
    weekday_of_day_one = datetime.date(year, month, 1).weekday()
    weekday_of_day = datetime.date(year, month, day)
    return (day - 1)//7 + 1 + (weekday_of_day < weekday_of_day_one)
```

However, if instead we want to get the nth of the weekday that date is, such as day 1 is the **1st** Friday, day 8 is the **2nd** Friday, and day 6 is the **1st** Wednesday, then we can simply return **(day - 1)//7 + 1**

Comment: It works well, but we need:

 weekday_of_day = datetime.date(year, month, day).weekday()

Answer (score 1):

The answer you are looking for is `(dm-dw+(dw-dm)%7)/7+1` where `dm` is the day of the month, `dw` is the day of the week, and `%` is the positive remainder.

This comes from relating the month offset (`mo`) and the week of the month (`wm`), where the month offset is how far into the week the first day starts. If we consider all of these variables to start at 0 we have

```
wm*7+dw = dm+mo
```

You can solve this modulo 7 for `mo` as that causes the `wm` variable drops out as it only appears as a multiple of 7

```
dw = dm+mo   (%7)
mo = dw-dm   (%7)
mo = (dw-dm)%7  (since the month offset is 0-6)
```

Then you just substitute the month offset into the original equation and solve for `wm`

```
wm*7+dw = dm+mo
wm*7 = dm-dw + mo
wm*7 = dm-dw + (dw-dm)%7
wm = (dm-dw + (dw-dm)%7) / 7
```

As `dm` and `dw` are always paired, these can be offset by any amount, so, switching everything to start a 1 only changes the the equation to `(dm-dw + (dw-dm)%7)/7 + 1`.

Of course the python `datetime` library starts `dm` at 1 and `dw` at 0. So, assuming `date` is a `datatime.date` object, you can go with

```
(date.day-1-date.dayofweek() + (date.dayofweek()-date.day+1)%7) / 7 + 1
```

As the inner bit is always a multiple of 7 (it is literally `dw*7`), you can see that the first `-date.dayofweek()` simply adjusts the value backwards to closest multiple of 7. Integer division does this too, so it can be further simplified to

```
(date.day-1 + (date.dayofweek()-date.day+1)%7) // 7 + 1
```

Be aware that `dayofweek()` puts Sunday at the end of the week.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. It is 100% correct. I've tested this one by using the calendar.monthcalendar as a source of truth and iterating from datetime.date.min up to datetime.date.max and the results were the same.  I just needed to change daysofweek() -> weekday() and remove the +1 at the end. Please check out this Gist for more details. https://gist.github.com/klement97/0912e56a8023741e87201fac0da261cd

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python2

import calendar, datetime

#FUNCTIONS
def week_of_month(date):
    """Determines the week (number) of the month"""

    #Calendar object. 6 = Start on Sunday, 0 = Start on Monday
    cal_object = calendar.Calendar(6)
    month_calendar_dates = cal_object.itermonthdates(date.year,date.month)

    day_of_week = 1
    week_number = 1

    for day in month_calendar_dates:
        #add a week and reset day of week
        if day_of_week > 7:
            week_number += 1
            day_of_week = 1

        if date == day:
            break
        else:
            day_of_week += 1

    return week_number


#MAIN
example_date = datetime.date(2015,9,21)

print "Week",str(week_of_month(example_date))
#Returns 'Week 4'
```

Answer (score 0):

Move to last day of week in month and divide to 7

```
from math import ceil

def week_of_month(dt):
    """ Returns the week of the month for the specified date.
    """
    # weekday from monday == 0 ---> sunday == 6
    last_day_of_week_of_month = dt.day + (7 - (1 + dt.weekday()))
    return int(ceil(last_day_of_week_of_month/7.0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do as follow:

1. **First extract the month and the week of year number**

```
df['month'] = df['Date'].dt.month
df['week'] = df['Date'].dt.week
```

2. **Then group by month and rank the week numbers**

```
df['weekOfMonth'] = df.groupby('month')["week"].rank("dense", ascending=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

One more solution, where Sunday is first day of week, base Python only.

```
def week_of_month(dt):
""" Returns the week of the month for the specified date.
TREATS SUNDAY AS FIRST DAY OF WEEK!
"""
    first_day = dt.replace(day=1)
    dom = dt.day
    adjusted_dom = dom + (first_day.weekday() + 1) % 7
    return (adjusted_dom - 1) // 7 + 1
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
def week_number(time_ctime = None):
    import time
    import calendar
    if time_ctime == None:
        time_ctime = str(time.ctime())
    date = time_ctime.replace('  ',' ').split(' ')
    months = {'Jan':1,'Feb':2,'Mar':3,'Apr':4,'May':5,'Jun':6,'Jul':7,'Aug':8,'Sep':9,'Oct':10,'Nov':11,'Dec':12}
    week, day, month, year = (-1, str(date[2]), months[date[1]], int(date[-1]))
    cal = calendar.monthcalendar(year,month)
    for wk in range(len(cal)):
        wstr = [str(x) for x in cal[wk]]
        if day in wstr:
            week = wk
            break
    return week

import time
print(week_number())
print(week_number(time.ctime()))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Answer (score 0):

An Easy way to get a week number of month;

if the datatype is datetime64 then

```
week_number_of_month = date_value.dayofweek
```

Answer (score 0):

the best solution that I found is this function

```
def get_week_of_month(date):
date = datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d") # date is str
first_day = date.replace(day=1)
print(first_day)
day_of_month = date.day
print(day_of_month)
print(first_day.weekday())
if(first_day.weekday() == 6):
    adjusted_dom = day_of_month + ((1 + first_day.weekday()) / 7)
else:
    adjusted_dom = day_of_month + first_day.weekday()
print(adjusted_dom)
return int(ceil(adjusted_dom/7.0))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
  import datetime
    
  def week_number_of_month(date_value):
            week_number = (date_value.isocalendar()[1] - date_value.replace(day=1).isocalendar()[1] + 1)
            if week_number == -46:
                week_number = 6
           return week_number
                
 date_given = datetime.datetime(year=2018, month=12, day=31).date()
                
 week_number_of_month(date_given)
```

Comment: datetime.datetime(year=2021, month=1, day=8).date()

Above case failed for this input

Answer (score -1):

This solution was intended to replicate the **Java** implementation of **WeekOfMonth** in **Python** and follow a pattern similar to the [ISO 8601 convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date).

1. First day of the week is Monday
2. Minimal number of days in the first week is 4. This implies weeks starting on and between Monday and Thursday inclusive are full weeks

   ```
       from datetime import date

       def week_of_month(calendar_date: date) -> int:
       """
         Python implementation of Week of Month
         following ISO 8601 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date,

         1. First day of the week is Monday
         2. Minimal days in the first week is 4 so
             weeks starting on and between Monday and Thursday
             inclusive are full weeks

         This function returns the week's number
         within a month for a calendar date

         :param calendar_date:
         :return: week of the month
       """
       _, month, _ = calendar_date.year, \
                     calendar_date.month, \
                     calendar_date.day
       _, week_of_year, _ = calendar_date.isocalendar()

       date_at_month_start = calendar_date.replace(day=1)
       _, month_start_week_of_year, month_start_day_of_week = \
           date_at_month_start.isocalendar()

       if month == 1:
           return 0 if week_of_year >= 51 else week_of_year

       elif month_start_day_of_week > 4:
           return week_of_year - month_start_week_of_year

       else:
           return week_of_year - month_start_week_of_year + 1
   ```