# Week of a month pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get week on a month, some months might have four weeks some might have five.
For each date i would like to know to which week does it belongs to.  I'm mostly interested in the last week of the month.

```
data = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(' 1/ 1/ 2000', periods = 100, freq ='D'))

0  2000-01-01
1  2000-01-02
2  2000-01-03
3  2000-01-04
4  2000-01-05
5  2000-01-06
6  2000-01-07
```

Answer (score 18):

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7029261/python-number-of-the-week-in-a-month) and decide which week of month you want.

There's nothing built-in, so you'll need to calculate it with apply.  For example, for an easy 'how many 7 day periods have passed' measure.

```
data['wom'] = data[0].apply(lambda d: (d.day-1) // 7 + 1)
```

For a more complicated (based on the calender), using the function from that answer.

```
import datetime
import calendar

def week_of_month(tgtdate):
    tgtdate = tgtdate.to_datetime()

    days_this_month = calendar.mdays[tgtdate.month]
    for i in range(1, days_this_month):
        d = datetime.datetime(tgtdate.year, tgtdate.month, i)
        if d.day - d.weekday() > 0:
            startdate = d
            break
    # now we canuse the modulo 7 appraoch
    return (tgtdate - startdate).days //7 + 1

data['calendar_wom'] = data[0].apply(week_of_month)
```

Comment: actually this would be an easy enhancement (already have ``weekofyear``), so extension (would be in cython): https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7986, if you would like to do a pull-request.

Comment: Your code results in "'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'to_datetime'" when applied to the example code of OP.

Comment: Also the result seems off. 91 2000-04-01 0
92 2000-04-02 0
93 2000-04-03 1
94 2000-04-04 1

-> 2000-04-03 should be the first week of April, not the second?

Comment: worked beautifully, thanks!

Comment: 0 through 5, that's 6 possible weeks. Doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 4):

I've used the code below when dealing with dataframes that have a datetime index.

```
import pandas as pd
import math

def add_week_of_month(df):
    df['week_in_month'] = pd.to_numeric(df.index.day/7)
    df['week_in_month'] = df['week_in_month'].apply(lambda x: math.ceil(x))
    return df
```

If you run this example:

```
df = test = pd.DataFrame({'count':['a','b','c','d','e']},
                     index = ['2018-01-01', '2018-01-08','2018-01-31','2018-02-01','2018-02-28'])
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

you should get the following dataframe

```
               count  week_in_month

2018-01-01     a              1
2018-01-08     b              2
2018-01-31     c              5
2018-02-01     d              1
2018-02-28     e              4
```

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR

```py
import pandas as pd

def weekinmonth(dates):
    """Get week number in a month.
    
    Parameters: 
        dates (pd.Series): Series of dates.
    Returns: 
        pd.Series: Week number in a month.
    """
    firstday_in_month = dates - pd.to_timedelta(dates.dt.day - 1, unit='d')
    return (dates.dt.day-1 + firstday_in_month.dt.weekday) // 7 + 1
    
    
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(' 1/ 1/ 2000', periods = 100, freq ='D'), columns=['Date'])
weekinmonth(df['Date'])
```

```
0     1
1     1
2     2
3     2
4     2
     ..
95    2
96    2
97    2
98    2
99    2
Name: Date, Length: 100, dtype: int64
```

### Explanation

At first, calculate first day in month (from this answer: [How floor a date to the first date of that month?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42285130/how-floor-a-date-to-the-first-date-of-that-month/42285363#42285363)):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(' 1/ 1/ 2000', periods = 100, freq ='D'), columns=['Date'])
df['MonthFirstDay'] = df['Date'] - pd.to_timedelta(df['Date'].dt.day - 1, unit='d')
df
```

```
         Date MonthFirstDay
0  2000-01-01    2000-01-01
1  2000-01-02    2000-01-01
2  2000-01-03    2000-01-01
3  2000-01-04    2000-01-01
4  2000-01-05    2000-01-01
..        ...           ...
95 2000-04-05    2000-04-01
96 2000-04-06    2000-04-01
97 2000-04-07    2000-04-01
98 2000-04-08    2000-04-01
99 2000-04-09    2000-04-01

[100 rows x 2 columns]
```

Obtain weekday from first day:

```py
df['FirstWeekday'] = df['MonthFirstDay'].dt.weekday
df
```

```
         Date MonthFirstDay  FirstWeekday
0  2000-01-01    2000-01-01             5
1  2000-01-02    2000-01-01             5
2  2000-01-03    2000-01-01             5
3  2000-01-04    2000-01-01             5
4  2000-01-05    2000-01-01             5
..        ...           ...           ...
95 2000-04-05    2000-04-01             5
96 2000-04-06    2000-04-01             5
97 2000-04-07    2000-04-01             5
98 2000-04-08    2000-04-01             5
99 2000-04-09    2000-04-01             5

[100 rows x 3 columns]
```

Now I can calculate with modulo of weekdays to obtain the week number in a month:

1. Get day of the month by `df['Date'].dt.day` and make sure that begins with 0 due to modulo calculation `df['Date'].dt.day-1`.
2. Add weekday number to make sure which day of month starts `+ df['FirstWeekday']`
3. Be safe to use the integer division of 7 days in a week and add 1 to start week number in month from 1 `// 7 + 1`.

Whole modulo calculation:

```py
df['WeekInMonth'] = (df['Date'].dt.day-1 + df['FirstWeekday']) // 7 + 1
df
```

```
         Date MonthFirstDay  FirstWeekday  WeekInMonth
0  2000-01-01    2000-01-01             5            1
1  2000-01-02    2000-01-01             5            1
2  2000-01-03    2000-01-01             5            2
3  2000-01-04    2000-01-01             5            2
4  2000-01-05    2000-01-01             5            2
..        ...           ...           ...          ...
95 2000-04-05    2000-04-01             5            2
96 2000-04-06    2000-04-01             5            2
97 2000-04-07    2000-04-01             5            2
98 2000-04-08    2000-04-01             5            2
99 2000-04-09    2000-04-01             5            2

[100 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: With your function it is possible to get WeekInMonth == 6 ? What is the 6ixt weekinmonth?

Comment: I think yes, in january of 2000, there is 6 weeks,  https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/monthly.html?year=2000&month=1&country=1

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do the trick for me

```
df_dates = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.bdate_range(df['date'].min(),df['date'].max())})
df_dates_tues = df_dates[df_dates['date'].dt.weekday==2].copy()
df_dates_tues['week']=np.mod(df_dates_tues['date'].dt.strftime('%W').astype(int),4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it subtracting the current week and the week of the first day of the month, but extra logic is needed to handle first and last week of the year:

```
def get_week(s):
    prev_week = (s - pd.to_timedelta(7, unit='d')).dt.week
    return (
        s.dt.week
        .where((s.dt.month != 1) | (s.dt.week < 50), 0)
        .where((s.dt.month != 12) | (s.dt.week > 1), prev_week + 1)
    )

def get_week_of_month(s):
    first_day_of_month = s - pd.to_timedelta(s.dt.day - 1, unit='d')
    first_week_of_month = get_week(first_day_of_month)
    current_week = get_week(s)
    return  current_week - first_week_of_month
```

Answer (score 0):

My logic to get the week of the month depends on the week of the year.

1. 1st calculate week of the year in a data frame
2. Then get the max week month of the previous year if the month is not 1, if month is 1 return week of year
3. if max week of previous month equals max week of current month
4. Then return the difference current week of the year with the max week month of the previous month plus 1
5. Else return difference of current week of the year with the max week month of the previous month

Hope this solves the problem for multiple logics used above which have limitations, the below function does the same. Temp here is the data frame for which week of the year is calculated using dt.weekofyear

```
def weekofmonth(dt1):
    if dt1.month == 1:
        return (dt1.weekofyear)
    else:
        pmth = dt1.month - 1
        year = dt1.year
        pmmaxweek = temp[(temp['timestamp_utc'].dt.month == pmth) & (temp['timestamp_utc'].dt.year == year)]['timestamp_utc'].dt.weekofyear.max()
        if dt1.weekofyear == pmmaxweek:
            return (dt1.weekofyear - pmmaxweek + 1)
        else:
            return (dt1.weekofyear - pmmaxweek)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import math

def week_of_month(dt:pd.Timestamp):
    return math.ceil((x-1)//7)+1
dt["what_you_need"] = df["dt_col_name"].apply(week_of_month)
```

This gives you week from 1-5, if days>28, then it will count as 5th week.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

def weekinmonth(dt: pd.Timestamp) -> int:
    return ((dt.day - 1 + pd.offsets.MonthBegin().rollback(dt).dayofweek) // 7) + 1

dates = pd.date_range("2023-12-01", "2024-02-01")

dates.map(weekinmonth)
```