# How to floor a date to the first date of that month?

Tags: python, date, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas DataFrame with index column = `date`.

Input:

```
            value
date    
1986-01-31  22.93
1986-02-28  15.46
```

I want to floor the date to the first day of that month

Output:

```
            value
date    
1986-01-01  22.93
1986-02-01  15.46
```

What I tried:

```
df.index.floor('M')
ValueError: <MonthEnd> is a non-fixed frequency
```

This is potentially because the df is generated by 
`df = df.resample("M").sum()` (The output of this code is the input at the beginning of the question)

I also tried `df = df.resample("M", convention='start').sum()`. However, it does not work.

I know in R, it is easy to just call `floor(date, 'M')`.

Comment: Is performance an issue?  I'd consider transforming the values into `datetime` objects for this, but this might be way to costly if you are trying to process millions of objects.

Answer (score 46):

there is a [pandas issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15303) about the floor problem

the suggested way is

```
import pandas as pd
pd.to_datetime(df.date).dt.to_period('M').dt.to_timestamp()
```

Comment: `df.date.dt.to_period('M').dt.to_timestamp()` seems to be sufficient, the initial `pd.to_datetime` is not needed.

Answer (score 19):

You can use timeseries offset MonthBegin

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthBegin
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']) - MonthBegin(1)
```

Edit:
The above solution does not handle the dates which are already floored to the beginning of the month. Here is an alternative solution.

Here is a dataframe with additional test cases:

```
            value
date    
1986-01-31  22.93
1986-02-28  15.46
2018-01-01  20.00
2018-02-02  25.00
```

With timedelta method,

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.index = df.index - pd.to_timedelta(df.index.day - 1, unit='d')


            value
date    
1986-01-01  22.93
1986-02-01  15.46
2018-01-01  20.00
2018-02-01  25.00
```

Comment: this is the only pandonic approach among all the answers (as a bonus this is vectorized)

Comment: There's a bug with this method: it'd translate any date to the beginning of the following month, except the beginning of the month, which stays the same. i.e. 1-1-2018 -> 1-1-2018, but 2-1-2018 -> 1-2-2018...

Comment: The timedelta method is right-on, worked perfectly for my use case, with one modification - adding the 'dt', so changing to 'df.index.dt.day' inside the to_timedelta().

Answer (score 11):

This will do the trick and no imports necessary. Numpy has a dtype `datetime64` which by default pandas sets to `[ns]` as seen by checking the dtype. You can change this to month, which will start on the first of the month by accessing the numpy array and changing the type.

```
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date.values.astype('datetime64[M]'))
```

It would be nice if pandas would implement this with their own `astype()` method but unfortunately you cannot.

The above works for data as datetime values or strings, if you already have your data as `datetime[ns]` type you can omit the `pd.to_datetime()` and just do:

```
df.date = df.date.values.astype('datetime64[M]')
```

Comment: I don’t know in which version they imported that to the pandas astype, but currently `df.date.astype('datetime64[M]')` works (version 1.2.2 at least). You could update this answer.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use string datetime formating:

`df['month'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-01')`

Answer (score 8):

Here's another 'pandonic' way to do it:

```py
df.date - pd.Timedelta('1 day') * (df.date.dt.day - 1)
```

Comment: This is very nice! Plus, it works with dask! (in contrast to Deo Leung's answer)

Comment: This also works well with variable instances of Timestamps in addition to being vectorized. Just change the `df.date` with your Timestamp and it works great!

Answer (score 3):

Assume that you are dealing with the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'MyDate': ['2021-03-11', '2021-04-26', '2021-01-17']})
df['MyDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df.MyDate)
```

Which is:

```
    MyDate
0   2021-03-11
1   2021-04-26
2   2021-01-17
```

And you want to truncate the date to month:

```
df['Truncated'] = df['MyDate'] + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(-1)
# OR    
# df['Truncated'] = df['MyDate'] - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)
df
```

And you get:

```
      MyDate  Truncated
0 2021-03-11 2021-03-01
1 2021-04-26 2021-04-01
2 2021-01-17 2021-01-01
```

**Important note**: This approach DOES NOT work when the date is already floored to the first day of the month, For that reason we will provide other solutions too.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'MyDate': ['2021-03-11', '2021-04-26', '2021-01-17', '2021-02-01']})
df['MyDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df.MyDate)

df['Truncated'] = df['MyDate'].dt.to_period('M').dt.to_timestamp()
print(df)
```

And you get:

```
 MyDate  Truncated
0 2021-03-11 2021-03-01
1 2021-04-26 2021-04-01
2 2021-01-17 2021-01-01
```

Finally, another approach could be the following:

```
df['Truncated'] = df['MyDate'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-01')
print(df)
```

And you get:

```
    MyDate   Truncated
0 2021-03-11  2021-03-01
1 2021-04-26  2021-04-01
2 2021-01-17  2021-01-01
```

Comment: your code won't work if date is first day of the month - it would became first day of the previous month

Answer (score 2):

```
dt_1 = "2016-02-01"
def first_day(dt):
    lt_split = dt.split("-")
    return "-".join([lt_split[0], lt_split[1], "01"])

print first_day(dt_1)
```

For Panda's DataFrame, you can use `dt["col_name_date"].apply(first_day)`.

Answer (score 1):

### From August 2019:

This should work:

```
[x.replace(day=1).date() for x in df['date']]
```

Only requirement is to make sure `date` is a datetime, which we can guarantee with a call to `pd.to_datetime(df['date'])`

Answer (score 1):

Liked Mikhail Venkov answer. Added below code to have the column added as a timestamp value and keep timezone information

```
    df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-01')).dt.tz_localize(timezone)
```

where timezone = 'America/Los_Angeles' or whatever zone you want

Answer (score 0):

One liner

```py
df.set_index(
    df.index - pd.to_timedelta(pd.to_datetime(df.index).day - 1, unit="D")
)
```

(there is a warning about vectorization.)

Actually what I would rather do is to first make that index a proper column, do the operations on it and then make it an index again:

```py
In [32]: df = pd.DataFrame(
                index=[datetime.date.fromisoformat("1986-01-31"), datetime.date.fromisoformat("1986-02-28")], 
                data={"value":[22.93, 15.46]})

In [33]: df
Out[33]:
            value
1986-01-31  22.93
1986-02-28  15.46

In [34]: df2 = df.reset_index().rename(columns={"index": "date"})

In [35]: df2
Out[35]:
         date  value
0  1986-01-31  22.93
1  1986-02-28  15.46

In [36]: df2.date = pd.to_datetime(df2.date)

In [37]: df2.date
Out[37]:
0   1986-01-31
1   1986-02-28
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]

In [38]: df2.date -= pd.to_timedelta(df2.date.dt.day - 1, unit="D")

In [39]: df2
Out[39]:
        date  value
0 1986-01-01  22.93
1 1986-02-01  15.46

In [40]: df2.set_index("date")
Out[40]: 
            value
date             
1986-01-01  22.93
1986-02-01  15.46
```

The most important line is:

```py
df2.date -= pd.to_timedelta(df2.date.dt.day - 1, unit="D")
```

where you actually remove the day offset.

Answer (score 0):

I needed both floor and ceiling functions. The following worked for me:

```
import pandas as pd

def monthfloor(ts):
    offset = pd.offsets.Hour(1)

    if offset.is_month_start(ts):
        return ts
    else:
        return ts - pd.offsets.MonthBegin()

def monthceil(ts):
    offset = pd.offsets.Hour(1)

    if offset.is_month_end(ts):
        return ts
    else:
        return ts + pd.offsets.MonthEnd()

begin = pd.Timestamp(2023, 4, 1)
middle = pd.Timestamp(2023, 4, 15)
end = pd.Timestamp(2023, 4, 30)

tss = pd.Series([begin, middle, end])

print(tss.map(monthfloor))
# 0   2023-04-01
# 1   2023-04-01
# 2   2023-04-01
# dtype: datetime64[ns]

print(tss.map(monthceil))
# 0   2023-04-30
# 1   2023-04-30
# 2   2023-04-30
# dtype: datetime64[ns]
```