# Pandas multi index/groupby

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame containing several registers from sold products, revenues, prices and dates

```
DATA        CLIENT     PRODUCT   PRICE
2020-08-28  xxxxxxx    RIOT      20.0
```

I am to group my information by year/month and product. I am running a group by to_period that extract the exactly information :

```
dfgmv = dfgift[['PRODUCT','PRICE']].groupby([dfgift.DATA.dt.to_period("M"), 'PRODUCT']).agg(['count','sum'])
```

This is the output :

```
                        PRICE
                        count   sum 
DATA       PRODUCT 
2020-08    RIOT         2       40.00
```

The question is that, as I export to excel, the date column is not interpreted as da date (yyyy-mm). I am trying to convert the yyyy-mm to something like yyyy-mm-dd so Excel understand it.

I´ve read several questions about multi index but my knowledge wasn't enough to use that info to apply here. I tried to change my index to datetime, but, as I run it, I lost the second index column (product).

```
dfgmv.index = pd.to_datetime(dfgmv.index.get_level_values(0).astype('datetime64[ns]'))
```

.

```
             VALOR  
             count  sum
DATA                
2020-08-01   2      40.00
```

So, How can I change the information format without losing my index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Index.set_levels` is designed to allow for the setting of specific index level(s).

```
dfgmv.index = (
    dfgmv.index.set_levels(dfgmv.index.levels[0].astype('datetime64[ns]'), level=0)
)
```

**Result**

```
                   PRICE      
                   count   sum
DATA       PRODUCT            
2020-08-01 RIOT        1  20.0
```

Comment: I am getting an error "ValueError: Level values must be unique: ' and hundreds of timestamp values.

Comment: Try this instead:  `dfgmv.index = dfgmv.index.set_levels(dfgmv.index.levels[0].astype('datetime64[ns]'), level=0)`

Comment: This worked. If I understood, instead of replacing the index for a new one, you just changed its format, that´s right?

Comment: Well Pandas loves to make copies of things.  So the flow of this would actually be that `dfgmv.index.levels[0].astype('datetime64[ns]'` actually returns a copy of the DatetimeIndex at level 0 with its type changed to `datetime64[ns]`.  Then `.set_levels(..., level=0)` uses that modified index level object to replace level 0 in a copy of the index that was created by `dfgmv.index`.  Then after all that the entire original index is overwritten with the new, modified index with `dfgmv.index = ...`.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your `groupby` to include [start of month](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42285489/19032206) for each date you have:

```
dfgmv = dfgift[['PRODUCT','PRICE']].groupby([dfgift.DATA.astype('datetime64[M]'), 'PRODUCT']).agg(['count','sum'])
dfgmv

                      PRICE
                      count     sum
DATA        PRODUCT         
2020-08-01  RIOT      1         20.0
```

Comment: Thanks. This way worked too!