# How to get week number from given date in range of 1 to 5 only, not in 1 to 52

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I'm working in machine learning regression problem where i predict sales value based on input features. In which date is one of the feature and i want to fetch month and week number from the date. Month gives in 1 to 12 that is okay. but for weeks i get between 1 to 52, which is also correct but i'm trying to get week number in range of 1 to 5, some months have 4 weeks and some have 5.

I have tried available methods for getting week number but it gives in range of 1 to 52 only. I can not just simply divide this by 4, otherwise no month will have 5 weeks.

this code gives output in range of 1 to 52 and i have also tried several other methods.

```
df['Week'] = df['Date'].dt.week
```

it should return like if a particular date is belong to fifth week of month than it should give week number 5.

Comment: "i'm trying to get week number in range of 1 to 5, some months have weeks and some have 5" Huh? If a date is in the 49th week of the year, why would you expect to get anything other than 49?

Comment: Are you trying to get week number relative to the month? Question is unclear.

Comment: @DeepSpace He wants the number of the week inside the month

Comment: @DeepSpace Any month with more than 28 days starts a 5th week

Comment: @kaushal -- see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806473/python-week-number-of-the-month

Comment: @Aryerez That gives you the modulo of the day of the week by 7 -- not sure how that tells you which week the date is in? E.g., both 2 % 7 and 23 % 7 == 2.

Comment: @MurrayW You are right. I meant using `// 7`, with `(month_day - 1) // 7 + 1`

Comment: @Aryerez thanks a lot for understanding query and your answer seems to be working in many case.

Answer (score 0):

Week number refers to week of year in most contexts. Week of month is not a standard notion and is thus not implemented in pandas. You can implement it yourself. See e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25249033/week-of-a-month-pandas) question on Stackoverflow.