# Extract Month and the week of the month

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am currently working on the pandas DataFrame with DateTime object. Is there a way to extract the month-weekofthemonth from pandas datetime object?

```
data = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(' 1/ 1/ 2020', periods = 7, freq ='D'))

0  2000-01-01
1  2000-01-02
2  2000-01-03
3  2000-01-04
4  2000-01-05
5  2000-01-06
6  2000-01-07

Expected:

0  2000-01-01       01-01
1  2000-01-02       01-01
2  2000-01-03       01-01
3  2000-01-04       01-01
4  2000-01-05       01-01 
5  2000-01-06       01-01
6  2000-01-07       01-01
7  2000-01-08       01-02 
8  2000-01-09       01-02
9  2000-01-10       01-02
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Week of a month pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25249033/week-of-a-month-pandas)

```
data[0].apply(lambda d: f'{d.month:02}-{(d.day-1) // 7 + 1:02}')
```

should give

```
0    01-01
1    01-01
2    01-01
3    01-01
4    01-01
5    01-01
6    01-01
7    01-02
8    01-02
9    01-02
```

Name: 0, dtype: object

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [Week of a month pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25249033/week-of-a-month-pandas)

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(' 1/ 1/ 2020', periods = 10, freq ='D'))
data['WoM'] = data[0].apply(lambda d : str(d.month) + '-0'+str(d.day//8+1))
print(data)
```

This gives you:

```
           0   WoM
0 2020-01-01  1-01
1 2020-01-02  1-01
2 2020-01-03  1-01
3 2020-01-04  1-01
4 2020-01-05  1-01
5 2020-01-06  1-01
6 2020-01-07  1-01
7 2020-01-08  1-02
8 2020-01-09  1-02
9 2020-01-10  1-02
```