# Timestamp GroupBy pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I am trying to group by on a timeseries dataset so that I can find most frequent day of week, week of month etc.

My dataset looks something like this:

```
ID Date      
1  2020-01-02
1  2020-01-09
1  2020-01-08
```

My output dataset should look something like this:

```
ID Pref_Day_Of_Week_A Pref_Week_Of_Month_A 
1  4                  2
```

(Here Thursday is the mode day of week, and the 2nd week is mode week of month for given dates)
So essentially trying to find out the mode(most frequent) day of week and mode(most frequent) week of month for each ID. Any idea how to achieve this in Python? The dataset contains multiple such IDs, this is just example of 1 such ID, the dataset has multiple IDs with similar timestamp data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use custom lambda function with select first mode by [`Series.mode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html) and [`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iat.html) in named aggregation by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID":[1,1,1,2,2,2],
                   "Date": ["2020-01-02", "2020-01-09", "2020-01-08"]*2})

#https://stackoverflow.com/a/64192858/2901002
def weekinmonth(dates):
    """Get week number in a month.
    
    Parameters: 
        dates (pd.Series): Series of dates.
    Returns: 
        pd.Series: Week number in a month.
    """
    firstday_in_month = dates - pd.to_timedelta(dates.dt.day - 1, unit='d')
    return (dates.dt.day-1 + firstday_in_month.dt.weekday) // 7 + 1
    

df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df['dayofweek'] = df.Date.dt.dayofweek
df['week'] = weekinmonth(df['Date'])

f = lambda x: x.mode().iat[0]
df1 = (df.groupby('ID', as_index=False).agg(Pref_Day_Of_Week_A=('dayofweek',f), 
                                            Pref_Week_Of_Month_A=('week',f)))
print (df1)
   ID  Pref_Day_Of_Week_A  Pref_Week_Of_Month_A
0   1                   3                     2
1   2                   3                     2
```

Comment: This gives the week of year , not the week of the month. Apart from that it works just fine

Comment: @sinha-shaurya - Can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64192858/2901002) for `df['week'] =weekinmonth(df['Date'])` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can group by `ID` using [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and then aggregate using [`.agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with *named aggregation* to set new column names for the 2 source columns `dayofweek` and `week`. Get mode by [`pd.Series.mode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID":[1,1,1,2,2,2],
                   "Date": ["2020-01-02", "2020-01-09", "2020-01-08", "2020-01-04", "2020-01-21", "2020-01-22"] })
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df['dayofweek'] = df.Date.dt.dayofweek
df['week'] = df.Date.dt.isocalendar().week

df_out = (df.groupby('ID', as_index=False)[['dayofweek', 'week']]
            .agg(Pref_Day_Of_Week_A=('dayofweek', lambda x:  pd.Series.mode(x)[0]), 
                 Pref_Week_Of_Month_A=('week', lambda x:  pd.Series.mode(x)[0]))
         )
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_out)

   ID  Pref_Day_Of_Week_A  Pref_Week_Of_Month_A
0   1                   3                     2
1   2                   1                     4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID":[1,1,1], "Date": ["2020-01-02", "2020-01-09", "2020-01-08"]})
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df['dayofweek'] = df.Date.dt.dayofweek
df['week'] = df.Date.dt.isocalendar().week
df[['ID', 'dayofweek', 'week']].mode()
```

output:

```
   ID  dayofweek  week
0   1          3     2
```

PS: dayofweek assumes the week starts on Monday, which is denoted by 0 and ends on Sunday which is denoted by 6. which makes Thursday day number 3

Comment: I think I should have mentioned that the dataset contains multiple IDs . So a groupby operation will be needed at some point

Comment: for mode with group by use: df[['ID', 'dayofweek', 'week']].groupby('ID').apply(pd.DataFrame.mode)

Comment: df=df.sort_values(by='Date')
df2=df.groupby('ID').agg(
    MODE_DAY_OF_WEEK=('Date',lambda x: stats.mode(x.dt.dayofweek)[0]))
I tried this . Is it correct though?It is difficult to manually verify this(stats is from scipy)