# Python code that returns the week of the month

Tags: python, date

I would like to know if there is a code that returns the week number of the month

for example, if the input data is November 2nd, 2022.
Then I would like the code to tell that it is the 1st week of the month.

The week should begin on Monday.

I tried looking for an answer in similar questions but could not find the right answer, could anyone help me out here?
Thanks :)

Comment: Of course there's code that does this, but this isn't a 'do it for you' website, you try it, then you come here for help

Comment: This should be a fairly trivial math problem with the *weekday as number* and the *day of the month* as inputs…

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Number of the Week in a Month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7029261/python-number-of-the-week-in-a-month)