# How to find out week no of the month in python?

Tags: python, python-datetime

I have seen many ways to determine week of the year. Like by giving instruction `datetime.date(2016, 2, 14).isocalendar()[1]` I get `6` as output. Which means 14th feb 2016 falls under 6th Week of the year. But I couldn't find any way by which I could find week of the Month.

Means IF I give input as `some_function(2016,2,16)`
I should get output as `3`, denoting me that 16th Feb 2016 is 3rd week of the Feb 2016

[ this is different question than similar available question, here I'm asking about finding week no of the month and not of the year]

Comment: Have you considered *writing one?*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python - Week number of the month](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806473/python-week-number-of-the-month)

Comment: To @Oin:  this is different question than similar available question, here I'm asking about finding week no of the month and note of the year

Comment: @PointNetworks that is also what the question I pointed to is asking.

Comment: to @Oin oh sorry I missed. You are right that was exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function did the work what I wanted

```
from math import ceil

def week_of_month(dt):

    first_day = dt.replace(day=1)

    dom = dt.day
    adjusted_dom = dom + first_day.weekday()

    return int(ceil(adjusted_dom/7.0))
```

I got this function from [This StackOverFlow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16804556/1922447)

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
def week_number_of_month(date_value):
    week_number = (date_value.isocalendar()[1] - date_value.replace(day=1).isocalendar()[1] + 1)
    if week_number == -46:
        week_number = 6
   return week_number
        
date_given = datetime.datetime(year=2018, month=12, day=31).date()
        
week_number_of_month(date_given)
```