# How to get week number based on date range in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have variable where I have stored week range   which is Essential =  'Dec 31, 2022 - Jan 6, 2023'
now I want to get week number for the Essential variable I  know the code for getting week no is
datetime.date(2023, 1, 4).strftime("%V") however is there any alternative for getting week number based on Essential variable ..i have tried every other alternative provided on internet  any help would be highly appreciated

Essential = 'Dec 31, 2022 - Jan 6, 2023'

Week number = 1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find out week no of the month in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35391731/how-to-find-out-week-no-of-the-month-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

If need convert second date by splitting by `-` use:

```
print (int(pd.to_datetime(Essential.split(' - ')[-1], format='%b %d, %Y').strftime("%V")))
1
```