# Nth week of Month calculation gives a wrong number in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a new variable that tells what week(nth week) of the month a certain date belongs to. For example, December 2020 has 5 weeks and Dec 8, 2020 belongs to the 2nd week of December. I already have date and month columns in my table and want to created a new column called "NthWeek".
For example I want something like this as my output.

```
  Date            Month     NthWeek
2020-12-08          12        2nd
2020-12-15          12        3rd
```

My current code is as follows and it works well for month like Dec 2020 but returns in accurate amount for a month like Oct 2020.

```
df['NthWeek'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda d: (d.day-1) // 7 + 1)
```

For example, October 5, 2020 is actually in the 2nd week of October, but my current calculation will just give me 1 (first week). Is there any way I can use a built-in calendar to get correct Nth weeks for all instances? How do I edit my code to make it work?

I'd appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python - Week number of the month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806473/python-week-number-of-the-month)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `weekday` function to get the weekday of the first of the month, and use that to determine the week you are in. It returns the day as an int, with 0 = Monday.

```
from calendar import weekday
wd = weekday(year, month, day)
```

E.g., if you determine the first of the month starts on day `wd`, you know the first week will end `6 - wd` days later. You can use this with your calculation by taking `day / 7` and comparing it to what day the month started.

The implementation I have in mind is the following:

```
from calendar import weekday
from math import floor
yr, mon, day = 2020, 10, 5
# check weekday on the first of the month in question.
wd = weekday(year=yr, month=mon, day=1)
# make it start at sunday=0 (assuming week is sun-sat).
wd = (wd+1)%7
# The month started on the day of the week wd (Sunday = 0).
# Thus our first week is only (7 - wd) days long.
wk = floor((day - wd) / 7.0) + 2
print(str(wk))
```

The final computation uses the fact that `day / 7 + 1` will give the week if we round down, assuming the week always starts on Sunday. Since it starts on day `wd`, we subtract this from `day`; now it is possible to find week -1, which means we're in the first (shorter than 7 days) week. This is why we add 2 rather than the 1 as before.

This computation should work in all instances. I hope this is what you're after.