# Getting Error "TypeError: get_week_of_month() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'month' and 'day' while tranforming date to week

Tags: python

I got a date column which includes time too. I stripped off the time and used the following function to transform the date to its respective week. However it is throwing an error;

```
    ar_data['prd_date'] = ar_data['prd_date'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
    
    ## function for setting the weekday
    import calendar
    import numpy as np
    calendar.setfirstweekday(0)
    
    def get_week_of_month(year, month, day):
        x = np.array(calendar.monthcalendar(year, month))
        week_of_month = np.where(x==day)[0][0] + 1
        return(week_of_month)
    
    get_week_of_month(2020,12,31)

ar_data['Week_predicted']=ar_data.apply(lambda x:get_week_of_month(x['prd_date']),axis=1)

Below is the error:
TypeError: get_week_of_month() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'month' and 'day'
```

Comment: `get_week_of_month()` expects 3 arguments, you are only providing 1 in `lambda x: get_week_of_month(x['prd_date'])`. Either rewrite your get_week_of_month function or break `x['prd_date']` down into year, month and day (3 seperate values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an easy function that would solve your problem. Just put it in your code instead of `get_week_of_month()`, it's from [a stackoverflow question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806473/python-week-number-of-the-month)

```py
from math import ceil

def week_of_month(dt):
    """ Returns the week of the month for the specified date.
    """

    first_day = dt.replace(day=1)

    dom = dt.day
    adjusted_dom = dom + first_day.weekday()

    return int(ceil(adjusted_dom/7.0))
```