# How can group each week of each month? - Python Panda

Tags: date

I would like to make a column of which week of the month. like the 2022-10-04 will be the first week of October. How should I do it ?

| Date |
| --- |
| 2022-10-04 |
| 2022-10-04 |
| 2022-10-06 |
| 2022-10-12 |
| 2022-10-19 |
| 2022-10-25 |
| 2022-10-31 |
| 2022-11-02 |
| 2022-11-03 |

I would like to look like this

| Date | Week |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-10-04 | Week1_Oct |
| 2022-10-04 | Week1_Oct |
| 2022-10-06 | Week1_Oct |
| 2022-10-12 | Week1_Oct |
| 2022-10-19 | Week2_Oct |
| 2022-10-25 | Week3_Oct |
| 2022-10-31 | Week4_Oct |
| 2022-11-02 | Week1_Nov |
| 2022-11-03 | Week1_Nov |

Comment: What's your prefered programming language? Happy to throw some code.

Comment: Hi it would be python. sorry about that

Comment: Please see the answer and hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out some code, but it seems that your sample data has a different result than mine.

```
import pandas as pd
from math import ceil
import calendar

#from this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806473/week-number-of-the-month
def week_of_month(dt):
    first_day = dt.replace(day=1)
    dom = dt.day
    adjusted_dom = dom + first_day.weekday()

    week_num = int(ceil(adjusted_dom/7.0)) 

    month_name = calendar.month_abbr[dt.month]

    return f'Week{week_num}_{month_name}'

#Creating a sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2022-10-04', '2022-10-04', '2022-10-06', '2022-10-19', '2022-11-02']})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df['week'] = df['date'].apply(week_of_month)

print(df)
```

Result:

| date | week |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-10-04 | Week2_Oct |
| 2022-10-04 | Week2_Oct |
| 2022-10-06 | Week2_Oct |
| 2022-10-19 | Week4_Oct |
| 2022-11-02 | Week1_Nov |