# Pandas - Grouping by month and summing a datetime index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a small Data Frame where the row index is date-time.  I want to sum the weeks into months, but am struggling.  Any suggestions?  Can't seem to figure out how to group by the index.

```
               A       B       C       D
Date                                      
2023-01-08  0.0000  0.7075  0.0000   0.000
2023-01-15  0.0000  1.0000  0.0000   0.000
2023-01-22  0.0000  1.0000  0.0000   0.000
2023-01-29  0.0325  0.9300  0.0000   0.025
2023-02-05  0.0250  0.9750  0.0000   0.000
2023-02-12  0.0050  0.5450  0.0000   0.000
2023-02-19  0.0000  0.1800  0.0000   0.000
2023-02-26  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000   0.000
2023-03-05  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000   0.000
2023-03-12  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000   0.000
2023-03-19  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000   0.000
2023-03-26  0.0000  0.4375  0.1875   0.000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert [`to_period`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_period.html):

```
df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df.index).to_period('M')).sum()
```

Output:

```
              A       B       C      D
Date                                  
2023-01  0.0325  3.6375  0.0000  0.025
2023-02  0.0300  1.7000  0.0000  0.000
2023-03  0.0000  0.4375  0.1875  0.000
```

##### alternative

[`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) on month start (`MS`):

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

out = df.resample('MS').sum()
```

Output:

```
                 A       B       C      D
Date                                     
2023-01-01  0.0325  3.6375  0.0000  0.025
2023-02-01  0.0300  1.7000  0.0000  0.000
2023-03-01  0.0000  0.4375  0.1875  0.000
```

Comment: @Barmar I added an alternative with `resample`, this way it's possible to use any frequency ;)

Comment: The resample version worked great. Thanks!  I want to divide the sum by the number of weeks that make up the sum.. any ideas?  Since some months will have 5 weeks.

Comment: @Jim you can calculate the week number of the last day of the month (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806473/week-number-of-the-month)). If you use `M` in place of `MS` in `resample` you'll get the last day of the month